# Passing Request Headers from oj.Collection or oj.Model

Tags: oracle-jet

Kindly help me by letting know, how can I pass headers, like Authorization etc., while calling a REST Endpoint from oj.Collection API

https://learncodeshare.net/2017/03/29/making-a-rest-call-from-oracle-jet/

I tried "customURL" from the above link, but could not get the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't explicitly mentioned in the docs, but you can add headers as one of the object input properties while calling the `collection.fetch()` method.

For e.g.:

```
self.model = oj.Model.extend({
        url: someURL,
        idAttribute: 'id'
});
var myModel = new self.model();
var collection = oj.Collection.extend({
        url: someURL,
        model: myModel
});
self.myCollection = new collection();

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    self.myCollection.fetch({
        headers: headers,
        success: function (collection, response, options) {
            resolve(response);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Ray. Will try this

Comment: Hi Ray
What is the type of "headers". Do I pass it as an object like {"bearer":"<token-val>"}

Answer (score 0):

customURL is the right place to send your authorization header. As per the documentation, it returns an object with multiple parameters. The first parameter is the REST URL, the second parameter is the type of operation (GET, POST etc - yes JET supports POST too), you can add additional parameters to pass to your rest call. An example is below:

```
returnCollection.customURL = function(operation, collection, options) {
    const requestBody = { param: 'somevalue' };
    return {
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/customsearch',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ...something...');
      },
      data: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    };
};
```

Comment: Hi, what is returnCollection

Comment: returnCollection is an instance of your oj.Collection.
const mycollection = oj.Collection.extend({
 ...,
 model: self.getModel()
});
const returnCollection = new mycollection();